# Calculating Errors of the Trapezoidal Rule in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods

I'm trying to calculate how the errors depend on the step, h, for the trapezoidal rule. The errors should get smaller with a smaller value of h, but for me this doesn't happen. This is my code:

Iref is a reference value calculated and verified with Simpson's method and the MATLAB function quad, respectively

```
for h = 0.01:0.1:1
    x = a:h:b;
    v = y(x);
    Itrap = (sum(v)-v(1)/2-v(end)/2)*h;
    Error = abs(Itrap-Iref)
end
```

I think there's something wrong with the way I'm using h, because the trapezoidal rule works for known integrals. I would be really happy if someone could help me with this, because I can't understand why the errors are "jumping around" the way the do.

Comment: First please note that the convergence of your Riemann Sum as h->0 is not "monotone", for the lack of a better word. Next is that -- could you explain your methods to calculate `Iref`? What do you mean by "verified" by Simpson's methods and `quad`? Both are approximations. Please clarify. In any case, please make the mathematics your question crystal clear. SO is for programming questions.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if maybe part of the problem is that not all intervals - for each step size `h` - have the same `a` and `b` just because of the way that `x` is constructed.  Try the following with the additional `fprintf` statement:

```
for h = 0.01:0.1:1
    x = a:h:b;
    fprintf('a=%f  b=%f\n',x(1),x(end));
    v = y(x);
    Itrap = (sum(v)-v(1)/2-v(end)/2)*h;
    Error = abs(Itrap-Iref);
end
```

Depending upon your `a` and `b` (I chose `a=0` and `b=5`) all the `a` values were identical (as expected) but the `b` varied from 4.55 to 5.0.

I think that you always want to keep the interval `[a,b]` the same for each step size that you choose in order to get a better comparison between each iteration. So rather than iterating over the step size, you could instead iterate over the `n`, the number of equally spaced sub-intervals within `[a,b]`.

Rather than

```
for h = 0.01:0.1:1
    x = a:h:b;
```

you could do something more like

```
% iterate over each value of n, chosen so that the step size
% is similar to what you had before
for n = [501 46 24 17 13 10 9 8 7 6]

    % create an equally spaced vector of n numbers between a and b
    x = linspace(a,b,n);

    % get the step delta
    h = x(2)-x(1);

    v = y(x);
    Itrap = (sum(v)-v(1)/2-v(end)/2)*h;
    Error = abs(Itrap-Iref);

    fprintf('a=%f  b=%f len=%d h=%f Error=%f\n',x(1),x(end),length(x),h,Error);
end
```

When you evaluate the above code, you will notice that `a` and `b` are consistent for each iteration, `h` is roughly what you chose before, and the `Error` does increase as the step size increases.

Try the above and see what happens!